# Optimizing Bitmap Loading in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, optimization, compact-framework

I'm in need to load an bunch of bitmaps in my application. The problem is that the loading make the form very slow. My actual class is as follows:

```
public class ImagensDisponiveis
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of  ImagemSygic struct
    /// </summary>
    private List<ImagemSygic> _poolImagens;
    /// <summary>
    /// index of next avaiable image
    /// </summary>
    private int indiceProximoDisponivel;
    /// <summary>
    /// Path to image folder
    /// </summary>
    private string caminhoPasta;
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of found images that conforms to patterm
    /// </summary>
    private int MAXCOUNT;


    public ImagensDisponiveis(string caminhoPastaRecursos)
    {
        indiceProximoDisponivel = 0;
        caminhoPasta = caminhoPastaRecursos;

        PreencherPool(out _poolImagens, caminhoPasta);
        MAXCOUNT = _poolImagens.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Preenche a lista de imagens com uma estrutura que contém a imagem e o caminho dessa imagem para o Sygic
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_poolImagens">The _pool imagens.</param>
    /// <param name="filepath">The filepath.</param>
    private void PreencherPool(out List<ImagemSygic> _poolImagens, string filepath)
    {
        DateTime momentoInicio = DateTime.Now;
        _poolImagens = new List<ImagemSygic>();
        string[] imagens = Directory.GetFiles(filepath);
#if DEBUG
        //int counter = 0;
        //int numFiles = imagens.Length;
#endif
        foreach (string caminhoImagem in imagens)
        {

            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(caminhoImagem);
                //original image to show on .net [POI]anything.bmp
                //image that sygic tries to use on drive ?[POI]anything.bmp, where ? is an number between 1 to 6
                bool valido = filename.StartsWith("[POI]", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
                //Log.writeToLog(caminhoImagem + " " + valido.ToString());
                if (valido)
                {

                    var streamImagem = File.Open(caminhoImagem, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    Bitmap temImagem = new Bitmap(streamImagem);
                    ImagemSygic tempImgSygic = new ImagemSygic();
                    tempImgSygic.CaminhoImagemSygic = caminhoImagem;
                    tempImgSygic.ImagemWindows = temImagem;
                    tempImgSygic.SygicImageID = -1;
                    _poolImagens.Add(tempImgSygic);
#if DEBUG
                    //counter++;

#endif
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException aec)
            {
                Log.writeToLog("[EXCEPCAO ImagensDisp]: ArgumentException - " + aec.Message);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
            {
                Log.writeToLog("[EXCEPCAO ImagensDisp]: UnauthorizedAccessException - " + uae.Message);
            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Log.writeToLog("[EXCEPCAO ImagensDisp]: Exception - " + exc.Message);
            }
        }

        DateTime tempoFim = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan duracao = tempoFim.Subtract(momentoInicio);
        Log.writeToLog("[Criacao da pool] Demorou " + duracao.TotalSeconds.ToString());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// OObtains the next avaianle ImagemSygic if there is an avaiable
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>ImagemSygic if possible, else null</returns>
    public ImagemSygic ObterProximoDisponivel()
    {
        if (indiceProximoDisponivel > MAXCOUNT)
            return null;
        else
        {
            ImagemSygic imagemRetornar = _poolImagens[indiceProximoDisponivel];
            indiceProximoDisponivel++;
            return imagemRetornar;
        }
    }

    public void ResetCounter()
    {
        indiceProximoDisponivel = 0;
    }


}

/// <summary>
/// Class that contains the Bitmap preview and the original path to that image
/// </summary>
public class ImagemSygic
{

    private volatile int _imageID;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the imagem windows.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The imagem windows.</value>
    public Bitmap ImagemWindows { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the caminho imagem sygic.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The caminho imagem sygic.</value>
    public string CaminhoImagemSygic { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the sygic image ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The sygic image ID.</value>
    public int SygicImageID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._imageID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._imageID = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class POISygic
{

    private volatile int _latitude;
    private volatile int _longitude;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the imagem.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The imagem.</value>
    public ImagemSygic Imagem { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the latitude.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The latitude.</value>
    public int Latitude { get { return this._latitude; } set { this._latitude = value; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the longitude.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The longitude.</value>
    public int Longitude { get { return this._longitude; } set { this._longitude = value; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the descricao.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The descricao.</value>
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is displayed now.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance is displayed now; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool isDisplayedNow { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the elem ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The elem ID.</value>
    public int elemID { get; set; }


}
```

The objective of this class is to read an serie of bitmaps that have the [POI] prefix to allow .net to display an legend in an form control to the poi image appearing in an  [Sygic Drive](http://www.sygic.com/) window.

The question is how i can optimize this code to load the images faster. At the moment it loads 26 315k bitmaps images in 10s. But probably in the final solution we could have as many as +260 images, so that is the reason of the need of optimization.

Comment: Whoa... what's that.. can we have it in English Please.. well i am going to google Translate... but..

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro Done, sorry but since my company is portuguese we do comments to important things in Portuguese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest potential improvement I see is that `PreencherPool` loads all images in a folder.  Are you showing all images at once?  If not, you could change that to lazy-load the images on demand, or at least load them in a background thread so the caller doesn't block while they all get loaded.

I'd also suggest that 300k seems a bit large for a "thumbnail" (which the code suggests they are).  Are you sizing it to what you actually need for displ15?

Comment: the size is fixed, a 24*32px 32bits ARGB image. And the format is that way because is what sygic drive uses. And doing an lazy loading how could it be done?

Comment: 24x32x32bpp is only 3k (24pixels*32pixels*4bytes/pixel), so there's a 2x order of magnitude difference in what you're reporting.  For lazy loading, don't load all of the images right away, instead, when a consumer calls for the Image, load it at that point and cache it so the first call loads it and subsequent calls get the cached version.